# Java- set xml element using xpath- positon

Tags: java, xml, dom, xpath, xmlnode

**Hi,**

I'm trying to set a specific element in a XML, by using xpath.
I need it to be in a specific location e.g. /UIM/INVOICE/SECTION/RECORD**[i+1]**

Do i need to use the "position()" method to do that? or how do i do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you construct the XPath expression at runtime and you have an integer value starting with 1 you can simply put that value in the predicate e.g. `int pos = i + 1; String path = "/UIM/INVOICE/SECTION/RECORD[" + pos + "]";`. That would select the *pos*th `RECORD` child element.